# OpenCV Limit FPS While Running

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using opencv python to do image processing. When I measure the FPS it's not stable. Sometimes FPS is 10 sometimes 12. I want to make FPS stable at 9 frame per second. Is there anyway to do that?

EDIT: I'm using my laptop's webcam. But I also have an Hikvision IP Camera. I need to do that independent from camera.
Here is how I'm measuring FPS.

```
while True:

      timer = cv2.getTickCount()
      ret, img = cap.read()

      fps = cv2.getTickFrequency()/(cv2.getTickCount()-timer)
      cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (75, 75),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
      cv2.imshow("Tracking", img)

      if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
         break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please clarify your question by answering: 1- Share the code you are running 2- Camera spec,model 3- How you measure fps

Comment: Try setting the camera fps before the loop: `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 9)`. I don't know what is the expected jitter when using Python and OpenCV but it's higher than using low level interface like C/C++ with threads, events and priority settings... If the camera doesn't support the fps setting feature, you may use relatively large buffer (queue ) of images and drop frames as needed.

Comment: This is typically handled by duplicating or dropping frames, to reach an exact frame rate, as in GStreamer's "videorate" operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you need that but here is your answer:

You can not expect a camera to give always exact/constant fps because of some low level device design configurations. If 30 fps written in a camera spec, its fps can vary 30~33.

What you can do is that you can pull 9 frames from the buffer in a sec and ignore the extra frames which camera feeds.

[Here](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/How-to-enforce-a-camera-to-run-at-CONSTANT-FPS/td-p/545078) is a good discussion to check.

Comment: Thank you, i guess this'll work for me.